# how do you set alpha vantage date as a column?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, alpha-vantage, mplfinance

I am trying to plot data from Alpha Vantage.

```
data = pd.read_excel(file)
```

when I do

```
print(data.columns)
```

I get:

```
    Index(['1. open', '2. high', '3. low', '4. close', '5.
    adjusted close', '6. volume', dtype='object')
```

as you can see, 'date' is not on there. this is causing me problems when I start using mplfinance and matplotlib. Can anyone help?

ps: my excel sheet looks like this

| date | 1. open ... |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-03 | 243 |
| 2021-02-02 | 245 |

Comment: mplfinance should have no problem plotting this with the date as an index column.  Given the data as is (immediately after `data = pd.read_excel(file)`) have you tried **`mpf.plot(data)`?**  If it doesn't work, please list the *entire* output.  Please also, immedately after your `data = pd.read_excel(file)` do: **`print(data.head())`** and **`print(data.tail())`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glancing at what you have shown as your excel file, it is possible that the data is backwards for mplfinance.

After `data = pd.read_excel(file)` try this before calling `mpf.plot()`:
**`data = data[::-1]`**.

Then call `mpf.plot(data)`

**Also**, it looks like you have numbers in your column names:

```
Index(['1. open', '2. high', '3. low', '4. close', '5.
    adjusted close', '6. volume', dtype='object')
```

(note: `'1. open'` instead of `'open'`)

So try reassigning the column names:

Thus, **this** should work:

```py
data = pd.read_excel(file)
data = data[::-1]
data.columns = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'adjusted close', 'volume']
mpf.plot(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works . I just added to make sure date is in the datetype type and set index to date. data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date)
data = data.set_index('date')

Answer (score 0):

The date is likely the index column, which is a special column not listed in `data.columns`. If you execute `print(data)` you should see the date column. If you want to convert the index column to a normal column do `data.reset_index()`.